# HighCharts: stacked bar shows percentages of stack

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently I have a stacked bar chart like this ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/))

[image]

I want to change the stacks so that each bar is converted to to a % of the total stack height. For example, in the Apples stack we currently have {3, 2, 5} for a total of 10.

Instead, I want to show {30%, 20%, 50%}. Of course, I could simply do the conversion myself before passing the data to HighCharts, but I want to still show the raw numbers {3, 2, 5} as the bar labels (in red above).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change the `plotOptions.column.stacking` property to `percent`.

Check more information and demos in the [HighCharts' `plotOptions.column.stacking` documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.stacking).

Comment: perfect, I knew there had to be an option somewhere :)

Comment: Can you do this dynamically? Have javascript changing the chart.options.plotOptions.column.stacking = "percent" and then update the chart somehow so that the chart that previously had normal stacking now displays percent stacking?

Comment: Tried doing this and then redrawing the chart with chart.redraw() ... no luck

Comment: @Bjorn, that's a completely different problem. In that case you need to `chart.destroy()`, update and recreate

Comment: @Jaskey, I've updated the reference to the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in your options:

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
       stacking: 'percent'
   }
}
```